# how to use `ant.parallel` in gradle script

Tags: java, gradle, parallel-processing, ant

- I have some folder in a array list
- then I want to use `list.foreach` to iterate them and copy them to another `toDir` folder
- each src folder in the list is no relation to another, so I think they can copy to `toDir` in parallel
- I think the code maybe like this, any one tell me does these code right?

```
       ant.parallel(threadsPerProcessor: 4) {
            listOfFolders().each { File folder ->
                ant.copy(todir: targetDir, preservelastmodified: true) {
                    filese
```

Comment: There's no useful reason to parallelize disk operations.

Comment: I want to copy A folder to C, and B folder to C；folder A and folder B can do copy at same time, "B" need not to wait "A" finished， so I want to use parallel make them faster

Comment: Parallel copy will not make it faster, it will only make your build more complicated. Disk is hundreds of times slower than your code.